# How to fetch nested json data from firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase

I want to create a dropdown menu from data that is coming from realtime database.
I have written few lines of code but not able to get subcategory
created an interface

```
export interface MenuInfo {
  name: string;
  subcategory?: MenuInfo[];
}
```

```
  menuList: MenuInfo[] = [];

  constructor(public dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMenuList();
  }

  getMenuList() {
    this.dataService.getMenuList().subscribe(data => {
      this.menuList = this.dataService.snapShotToArray(data);
      console.log("menulist"+ this.menuList[0].subcategory);
    });
  }
```

```
  getMenuList() {
    return this.fdb.list('category').snapshotChanges();
  }
```

```
  snapShotToArray(snapShot) {
    let retArr: any[] = [];
    snapShot.forEach(element => {
      let obj: any = {};
      obj = element.payload.val();
      obj.key = element.key;
      retArr.push(obj);
    });

    return retArr;
  }
```

This is json data from firebase.

```
category
   -LtygKwodI5HdptwuInj
     name: "Helmet"
     subcategory
       -LtygbtNUgCPC4paDswy
          name: "full-face"
```

How should i do to create dropdownmenu.
[image]

Comment: what is log output?

Comment: I'm geting category name but not its subcategory `ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

Comment: subcategory is not an array. You can not use ngFor on it

Comment: Is it a sub collection? If so, just do ref.collection('something').doc('a').collection('else').doc('b')

Comment: since it is a single object, you can just use `{{subcategory.name}}` in your html code

Comment: later it will be array of objects

Comment: Can someone tell how to use Object.key for mapping.

Comment: What is the problem

Comment: Not able to get subcategory data

Comment: Add `console.log(element);` and tell me what you get

Comment: `{payload: DataSnapshot, type: "value", prevKey: null, key: "-LtygKwodI5HdptwuInj"}
key: "-LtygKwodI5HdptwuInj"
payload: DataSnapshot
index_: PriorityIndex {}
key: (...)
node_: ChildrenNode {children_: SortedMap, priorityNode_: ChildrenNode, indexMap_: IndexMap, lazyHash_: null}
ref: (...)
ref_: Reference {repo: Repo, path: Path, queryParams_: QueryParams, orderByCalled_: false}
__proto__: Object
prevKey: null
type: "value" `

Comment: @Joy have you tried the answer?

Comment: yes i got the answer but used different way.snapchotchanges and pipe and mapping.

Comment: @Joy okay if the answer helped you please upvote it and mark it as correct so others know that it is helpful thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After retrieving the `key` add a reference to node `subcategory`, subscribe to the observable and then using forEach you can access the value of `name` inside subcategory:

```
snapShot.forEach(element => { 
  let lists = this.fdb.list("category/"+element.key+"/"+"subcategory").snapshotChanges();
  lists.subscribe(data => { 
    data.forEach(subElem => {
      console.log(subElem);
  });
 });
});
```